# Expose virtual machine to internet [pentest lab]

Tags: linux, virtualization

I would like to create a virtual machine using virtual box for making a hacking lab and allow someone to try to hack it from internet. (So the virtual machine would be the victim). How can I do that? All the devices in my lan, virtual machines included share a unique ip i guess, so how can I expose my virtual machine? Is there a way? Should i setup port forwarding or use some other configuration? I apologize if this is a stupid question. Hope someone can help me if possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: ***"All the devices in my LAN, Virtual Machines included, share a unique IP.."*** Wait, do you mean to say that they all *share* the same IP address? Or that they all have *unique* IP addresses?

Answer (score 0):

You should be very careful about what you plan on doing. If you want to expose the VM to the internet you should make absolutely sure that the VM is not able to communicate with the other devices in your network. Nevertheless, the attacker will be able to use your internet connection for illegal activites. It will be hard to prevent that and it requires a solid understanding of networking techniques. All in all, my advice is: don't do it, unless you absolutely know what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm aware of the security risks, though I would like to try to do it. I would try to isolate the virtual machine and make it available only for a limited time for testing, then i'd switch it off or delete it. I hope someone can point me in the right direction for making available my virtual machine from the internet. I would like to collect info and do it when I'm ready. It's a way to learn new things for me.I know how to do it using a vps for example cuz it has a own ip,though i'd like to do it with a own virtual machine under a NAT.I think i should use port forwarding

Comment: Well, you can use port forwarding. You have to forward the ports in your router config. Default is usually to not forward anything. Which ports you have to forward depends on which services the VM will offer.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of device do you have for a router? Do you have shell access?

I had to help someone get full access to their box from the internet. I wasn't able to find an option in the web UI of the router (running Tomato), so I applied the changes directly, and then saved my changes in **/etc/iptables**. These changes would be wiped when the config was changed, though this might not be an issue depending on your choice of router.

The SNAT rule makes the packet appear to come from your local address (censored to 1.1.1.1 in this case) when the packet leaves your network for the internet. Many Linux router distributions like to implement their port forwarding with SNAT instead of the MASQUERADE rule that can be found by default.

`iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -o vlan1 -j SNAT --to-source 1.1.1.1`

When someone from the outside attempts to connect to your public IP, the connection is sent to the local machine (192.168.0.123). Before it can reach the machine, it must first be accepted by the FORWARD chain.

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 1.1.1.1 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.123`

If it makes it is accepted,  forwarded to the local machine.

`iptables -A FORWARD -d 192.168.0.123 -j ACCEPT`

For your honeypot example, you might want a global accept like I posted above, though for my use case I wanted to restrict access to a known trusted IP, instead using this:

`iptables -A FORWARD -d 192.168.0.123 -s 2.2.2.2 -j ACCEPT`

If you're letting absolutely anybody connect to your location, I would place it on a completely separate subnet/collision domain  to your normal computers, and make that your `iptables` setup bars all access to that domain.

Comment: I have a normal Netgear router (nothing at enterprise level) and I could telnet into it by enabling the debug mode. Thanks for you answer :)